# How can I send a message on a webpage, which requires reCAPTCHA, without being able to see a reCAPTCHA box

Tags: web, captcha

For places where reCAPTCHA service isn't available, e.g. reCAPTCHA box is not shown in mainland China, the problem could lead to

> CAPTCHA
>
> The reCAPTCHA was invalid. Go back and try it again.

Is there anyway to overcome that?

For example, some website requires reCAPTCHA verification before sending them a message via their Contact Me webpage, for instance, https://www.chinasource.org/about/contact/

- Is there a way to perform reCAPTCHA verification without being able to see its box?
- Or is there a way to find out the email address to bypass reCAPTCHA verification? Is it possible to find the email address in the source html of the webpage? (I can't find it.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149677/discussion-on-question-by-tim-how-can-i-send-a-message-on-a-webpage-which-requi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: A js library necessary for entering the chat room is banned by GFW. What you did helps CCP censor free speech @DavidPostill

Comment: Contents of the chat room: https://i.imgur.com/crXEfLL.png

Comment: @Gantendo thanks. imgur is cencored, including the pictures hosted for stack exchanges.

Comment: @Tim they dont want you to see our cat pictures... https://ibb.co/fML6QXr & https://i.postimg.cc/HWhSQ27z/aaacr-XEf-LL.png